# how would you solve a polar coordinate PDE when one side of the circle is not given any condition

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I am just wondering how would you solve the following PDE if you are not given the "inner circle" boundary condition:
[image]

So it is given that $u(a, \theta) = \sin(4\pi)$, but nothing is given about $u(1,\theta)$.

I have sketched the graph here, as shown here the inner part is not given any condition. Although I know as $r$ approach $0$, $u(r,\theta)$ is bounded, but it seems this is not relevant as the domain of $r$ won't be less than $1$. So how would I go about solving this?
[image]

I know this is a Two step problems. I could solve the $\theta$ problem. But not sure how to solve the "R" problem since it seems that nothing is given about the function when $r = 1$. $u(1,0)=?$ $ u(1, \theta)=?$

Comment: Perhaps it was a typo and they meant as $r\rightarrow1\ \  u(r,\theta)<\infty$, or maybe $r$ is actually bounded between $0$ and $a$?

Comment: @Eli it is really bad that if a person get stuck on the problem for 2, 3 days and end up there is indeed a typo as this question is not very hard to solve if indeed what you said is true.

Comment: I'd guess there's an implied insulation condition, in which case the solution oughtta [look like so](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0wMv3.jpg) - as generated by [this web page](https://marksmath.org/classes/Spring2021PDE/demos/SteadyStateHeatExplorer2D.html), where (like a lot of numerical software) the insulation condition is, indeed, implied.

Comment: If you do think there's an error or omission in the statement of the problem, I recommend considering it to be a learning experience and potentially *more* valuable to consider ways to fix the problem. It's certainly not realistic to think that sort of thing *never* happens.